# Why doesn't appending to list via non-existent indexes do what I expect?

Tags: r, list, append, indices

I want to achieve the following outcome in a list:

```
[[1]]
[1] "one"

[[1]]
[2] "two"
```

I would like to ask why the next way in doing so, by using indexes, fails:

```
List <- list()
List[[1]][1] <- "one"
List[[1]][2] <- "two"
```

Comment: There's nothing to index with `[1]`.  It's non-existent.  You can just use `List[[1]] <- "one"`

Comment: You are right, I noticed it, but I wonder if there is a way to create this position by an index. That's why I posed the question.

Answer (score 2):

If we do not use index the first time we append, it works fine:

```
List <- list()
List[[1]]<- "one"
List[[1]][2]<- "two"
```

As [Richard Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/richard-scriven) noticed correctly,

```
List[[1]][1]<- "one"
```

fails because position 1 does not exist. But this is true also for position 2 in the solution above. And this is somehow strange.

Comment: Yeah that's why I didn't post an answer.  It's hard to explain, but you get it.  I believe it's because you are trying to assign position 1 to a vector that does not already exist.  That being list element 1.

Comment: You should post it as an answer because I find it a little bit tricky for someone to know it.

Comment: Well it's just like saying `x[1] <- 1` without previously creating `x`.  It just so happens that list element 1 is the vector in question

Comment: You are right. It is the same behavior. Anyway tnx alot